# Select only value attribute which have numbers in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have lots of input tags with `type text` and `number` respectively. I want to replace all `input type text` which have values in numbers to the `input type number` but not getting how to take only numbers in value. I'm using below code to do it.

```
$( "[value*='']").attr('type','number');
```

Comment: Note that the *current* value of an input is not accessible on its `value` *attribute*; the `value` *attribute* only represents the input's *default* value. (There is no attribute for its current value.) So you can't use a CSS selector to select on an input's current value. (Separately: `[value*='']` will never match anything, as you're asking it to match a non-blank `value` attribute that contains a blank string. To just find ones with a value attribute, regardless of its content, use `[value]`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `.filter` and use `isNaN` to check whether the value is number or not

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='text']").filter(function() {
    return !isNaN( $(this).val() ) && $(this).val().trim() !== "";
  }).attr("type", "number");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Javascript">
<input type="text" value="Apple">
<input type="text" value="1">
<input type="text" value="3">
<input type="text" value="1000">
<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: `? false : true` what? Why not simply negating it (`!`) ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oppss.. Updated

Comment: It's works. Thanks to everyone. But why there is downvote?.

Comment: Got error. Actually all others input also replaced with type number even they don't have value attribute

Comment: @SagarKodte Then you use something like `return !isNaN( $(this).val() ) && $(this).val() !== "";`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe iterating and checking will do it:

```
for(const el of $("[value*='']").toArray())
  if(parseInt(el.value))
    $(el).attr('type','number');
```

Comment: Hi, not working. When i hit this in console giving undefined